# Regex not working in javascript split method but working Online test websites

Tags: javascript, csv, split, javascript-objects, csvtoarray

i have this Regex `(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)\\\\n` working on online test website perfectly but not in Below code. i have a string with multiple `\n` and also some with in `"` double Quotation but i want to ignore all `\n` with in `"` double Quotes.

```
let input = "a,b,c\n'aa\nbb\ncc'\nhello world";
    
    const lines = input.split("(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)\\\\n");
    console.log(lines);
```

i am getting this output
[image]

want this Output:

```
[0]: "a,b,c"
    [1]: "aa\nbb\ncc"
    [2]: "hello world"
```

Comment: Btw, regex isn't created in JavaScript in this way

Comment: can you write here how to write then ? in case we want to use in JS

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

```js
let input = "a,b,c \n 'aa\nbb\ncc' \n hello world";
console.log(input.split(' \n '))
```

Comment: no spaces is in actual string something like...
"a,b,c\n'aa\nbb\ncc'\nhello world"

Answer (score 0):

There was some ambiguity between your explanation and your sample data. You were talking about double quotes as a delimiter in your input, but it was the opposite in the sample. There were also too many escape characters before the `\n` in the regex. `\\\\n` becomes `\n`. Not `\\n` because in a javascript string `\n` stands for the actual newline character. No need to esacpe it in the regex.

```js
let input = 'a,b,c\n"aa\nbb\ncc"\nhello world';
    
let lines = input.split(/(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)\n/);
console.log(lines);
```